# Remove key from known_hosts file in ChromeOS

Tags: ssh, google-chrome-os

With the very limited ChromeOS crosh shell, how do I remove a host key from my known_hosts file in ChromeOS.

Answer (score 8):

The ChromeOS crosh shell command `ssh_forget_host` is a menu driven tool to remove host keys from the known_hosts file.

```
crosh> ssh_forget_host
Known hosts:
 1) 192.168.1.6
 2) 192.168.1.8
 3) 192.168.1.7
 4) 192.168.1.10
 5) 192.168.1.5
Please select a host to forget [1-5]:
```

Comment: might only work in dev mode